# How to process locally withdrawn data from Django REST Framework in Select2?

Tags: javascript, python, django, rest, jquery-select2

I'm trying to process results I get from Django REST Framework in select2 plugin according examples they have on their site, but only I get is:

[image]

I.e. unclickable and unsearchable list of text. It just doesn't work in a way select2 should work.

Here is the code:

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax">
    <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
          ajax: {
            url: "/news/aff/users/?format=json",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term.email
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            email: item.user_email
                        }
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
          },
          minimumInputLength: 0,
          templateResult: function(data) {
            return data.email;
          },
          templateSelection: function(data) {
            return data.email;
          }
        });


</script>
```

and here how does the structure in Django REST look like:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve it? I am also facing the problem and could not solve it!

Answer (score 0):

You should provide object with `id` and `text` property in order for Select2 to work properly.

So your code should be updated to something like that:

```
    $(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
      ajax: {
        ...
        data: function (term) {
        return {
            id: term.url,
            text: term.user_email
            };
        },
      ...
      },
      ...
    });
```